# How can I change video attr src from another html file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to change the video src when a certain button is pressed.

File 1 and File 2 are in the same directory

```
Html file 1:

<div class="videoplayer">
<video class="video" src="videos/something.mp4" controls >

</video>
```

```
Html file 2:

<div class="button">
<input class="changeSrc" type="button" name="bttn" 
value="Change video src!" onclick="ChangeVideoSrc()">
</div>



Script file 2:

function ChangeVideoSrc() {
 ???
};
```

My question is: How can I set from file 2, the video src of file 1. I read about sharing the variables with a cookie, or local storage but I didn't understand it. I hope there is some magic javascript or jquery syntax to do it directly.

Comment: Why don't you try $(.video').attr('src', 'videos/desired_video.mp4') directly inside the function 'ChangeVideoSrc()'?

Comment: Are both files getting rendered on the same page?

Comment: @Zammy Both files are in the same directory, i dont know if that is what you mean

Comment: We need to know more about your structure, do you open the html file #1 from your html #2 ? Or are they both loaded at the same moment ?

Comment: @kmg mmm because jquery selector is not gonna find .video class since .class doesnt exist in html file 2. Am i rigth?

Comment: _“Both files are in the same directory, i dont know if that is what you mean”_ - you can not use client-side JavaScript to change anything in “files”. Both of your HTML documents would need to be displayed at the same time in the browser (different windows/frames) for any direct “communication” between the two to be possible in the first place. Otherwise, if they are not displayed simultaneously, you need to find a way to _store_ information somewhere, so that one document can write it, and the other read it at a later time.

Comment: I think, send file2 value by ajax and get that by this form `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript` will be okay

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `localstorage`. set a data when `button` clicked, get it on video page. Also you can use `cookie` but `localstorage` is simpler and faster to use.

```js
// From first page:


$('.changeSrc').click(function() {
  window.localStorage.setItem('changeSrc', 'yes');
});

// From second page:

var $status = window.localStorage.getItem('changeSrc');
if($status == 'yes'){
$('.video').attr('src', 'videos/new_src.mp4')
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- From first page: -->

<div class="button">
  <input class="changeSrc" type="button" name="bttn" value="Change video src!">
</div>

<!-- From second page: -->

<div class="videoplayer">
  <video class="video" src="videos/something.mp4" controls>
</video>
```

***Note that*** this code not working here, in this snippet, you have to try in your local! ***Update:*** I added `jsfiddle`

**[Working Example](https://jsfiddle.net/ggf26j35/)**

Comment: Worked perfectly.